# Find the Next Closest Time in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, date, data-structures, time

I have a problem where I have to find the next closest time where a given time is in the format HH:MM.

I wrote the following algorithm:

```
def nextClosestTime(time):
    time = list(time)
    c = (int(time[0])*10 + int(time[1]))*60 + int(time[3])*10 + int(time[4])
    digits = [time[0],time[1],time[3],time[4]]

    diff = 24*60
    # there are 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 permutations 
    ans = []
    ans = ans + time

    one = [x for x in digits if int(x)<3]
    two = [x for x in digits]
    three = [x for x in digits if int(x)<6]
    four = [x for x in digits]

    for i in range(len(one)):
        time[0] = one[i] 
        for j in range(len(two)):
            time[1] = two[j]
            if time[0]==2 and time[1]>4:
                continue
            for k in range(len(three)):
                time[3] = three[k]
                for l in range(len(four)):
                    time[4] = four[l]                    
                    t = (int(time[0])*10 + int(time[1]))*60 + int(time[3])*10 + int(time[4])
                    if t>c and t-c< diff:
                        diff = t-c 
                        ans = time

    return "".join(x for x in ans)

print(nextClosestTime("19:34"))
```

However, my answer is 14:44 even though the `ans` gets updated only once when the time is valued at 19:39.

After that `ans` never gets updated as 19:39 has the minimum `diff`. So, why does the `ans` change?

It this some shallow copy or deep copy issue in python?

I thought so and thus instead of just doing `ans = time` while defining the variable, I did `ans = []` and then `ans = ans + time` to initialize.

Any help would be great. Also, any better way is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, after you have assigned `time` to `ans` you continue to change the contents of `time` elements. Those elements are *the same* as the ones you see in `ans`, as `ans` and `time` refer to the same list.

You need to take a copy of `time` when you assign it to `ans`:

```
               if t>c and t-c< diff:
                    diff = t-c 
                    ans = time[:] # take a copy
```

Now your function will output:

```
19:39
```

#### Optimisation

A more efficient algorithm would first check which is the unique list of digits, sort them and determine the position of each original digit in that sorted list.

Then, starting with the last digit, look up what the next available digit is in that sorted list. If there is one, and the resulting time is valid, return that as solution.

If it was already the last digit in the sorted list, or the resulting time is invalid, change that digit to the smallest available value (first digit in the sorted list). Then repeat the above for the remaining digits.

Code:

```
def nextClosestTime(time):
    digits = [int(digit) for digit in time if digit.isdigit()]
    uniques = sorted(set(digits))
    pos = [uniques.index(digit) for digit in digits]

    for i in range(3, -1, -1):
        pos[i] += 1
        if pos[i] < len(uniques):
            digits[i] = uniques[pos[i]]
            if digits[2] < 6 and digits[0]*10+digits[1] < 24:
                return "{}{}:{}{}".format(*digits)
        digits[i] = uniques[0]

    return "no solution"

print(nextClosestTime("15:56")) # 16:11
```

Comment: I did ans = time[:] still I get the same 14:44 answer!!

Comment: See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/NextTimeSameDigits). Are you sure you made the change at the right place?

Comment: https://ideone.com/UyDBFO I tried I made the change while defining the variable ans

Comment: Please look at the link I gave you: you made the change at the wrong place. You should do it in the `if`. I have now added more context in my answer to make it clear.